# GCP cloud-run - Python code does not leave stack-trace when it crashes

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, crash-dumps

I have a strange situation when I deploy a python flask based service on GCP cloud-run.

I have some bug in my code that results in a crash as a part of processing some web API. But GCP cloud-run logs don't show anything except just a 500 error message. The same code, when I deploy locally on my machine throws a proper exception with the line number and other details. How do I get GCP cloud-run logs to show all that? All other logs from my code (other print statements, logger output, etc.) shows reliably. It is just these python exceptions that dont show up - making it impossible to troubleshoot issues that happen in production.

I am attaching an image that shows GCP logger output. You see the 500 error there but nothing about where i my code the exception happened and such.

[image]

Comment: How do you log in your code? Can you share this part of your code?

Comment: I am using Python's logging module to log - the messages that you see in that image are coming from there. But the crash and stack-trace that I want to see wont be an explicit log from me anyway....I am not sure where GCP puts those messages and why they dont show up on these logs.

To your specific question - I simply use logging.getLogger("my-log-name").critical("my message")

Comment: Turns out, my issue had to do with using gunicorn to build and deploy the cloudrun instance

Comment: @sachinsdesai, please post your comment as an answer in order for other community members to find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a community wiki as @sachinsdesai mentioned that the issue occurred when using `gunicorn` when building and deploying the Cloud Run instance.

Answer (score 0):

In my Dockerfile, I had to replace the first line with the 2nd line for it to work. I still have not found an explanation for it. But I am happy to have made the change - debugging is much easier - especially for long-lived application where one does not always have the luxury to instrument code reproduce problems that happen unexpectedly.

```
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 my_main:app

CMD [ "python", "-u", "my_main.py"]
```